# Run Powershell Graph script from Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, graph

I have the following script to schedule an event on an O365 calendar.

The goal is to run this script from an Asp.net C# page.
If I run it in WindowPowershell ISE, it works perfectly.
The problem is when I run it from the page.

It returns me the following error: *"The term 'Connect-MgGraph' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."*

**C# CODE**

```
public static string SetEvent(string Subject, string Date, string StartHour, string EndHour, string Location, string[] Attendees, string Body)
        {
            string result = "";
    
            try
            {
                //Subject
                string strSubject = Subject;
    
                //Param StartDateHour && EndDateHour
                DateTime datDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
                string strStartDateHour = datDate.Year.ToString() + "-" + datDate.Month.ToString() + "-" + datDate.Day.ToString() + "T" + StartHour;
                string strEndDateHour = datDate.Year.ToString() + "-" + datDate.Month.ToString() + "-" + datDate.Day.ToString() + "T" + EndHour;
    
                // Location
                string strLocation = Location;
    
                // Attendees
                string strAttendees = "@(";
    
                foreach (string item in Attendees)
                {
                    strAttendees += "@{EmailAddress = @{" +
                    "Address = ' + item.ToString() + ' " +
                    "} " +
                    "Type = 'Required'" +
                "}";
                }
    
                strAttendees += ")";
    
                // Body
                string strBody = Body;
    
                //Secrets!
                
    
                string strAppID = HIDDEN;
                string strTenantID = HIDDEN;
                string strClientSecret = HIDDEN;
    
                // create Powershell runspace
                RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
                Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
                runspace.Open();
    
                RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
    
                string scriptfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/PowerShell/scripts/Calendar/SetEvent.ps1");
    
                // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile);
    
                CommandParameter SubjectParam = new CommandParameter("subject", strSubject);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(SubjectParam);
                CommandParameter StartDateHourParam = new CommandParameter("startdatehour", strStartDateHour);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(StartDateHourParam);
                CommandParameter EndDateHourParam = new CommandParameter("enddatehour", strEndDateHour);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(EndDateHourParam);
                CommandParameter LocationParam = new CommandParameter("location", strLocation);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(LocationParam);
                CommandParameter AttendeesParam = new CommandParameter("attendees", strAttendees);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(AttendeesParam);
                CommandParameter BodyParam = new CommandParameter("body", strBody);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(BodyParam);
                CommandParameter AppIDParam = new CommandParameter("appid", strAppID);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(AppIDParam);
                CommandParameter TenantIDParam = new CommandParameter("tenantid", strTenantID);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(TenantIDParam);
                CommandParameter ClientSecretParam = new CommandParameter("clientsecret", strClientSecret);
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(ClientSecretParam);
    
                pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    
                pipeline.Invoke();
                runspace.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ex.Message;
            }
    
            return result;
        }
```

**POWERSHELL CODE**

```
    [string]$subject,
    [string]$startdatehour,
    [string]$enddatehour,
    [string]$location,
    [string]$attendees,
    [string]$appid,
    [string]$tenantid,
    [string]$clientsecret
)

Import-Module MSAL.PS
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Calendar

#Generate Access Token to use in the connection string to MSGraph
$AppId = $appid
$TenantId = $tenantid
$ClientSecret = $clientsecret

$MsalToken = Get-MsalToken -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId -ClientSecret ($ClientSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
 
#Connect to Graph using access token
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $MsalToken.AccessToken -Scopes "User.Read.All","Calendars.ReadWrite"

$params = @{
    Subject = $subject
    Start = @{
        DateTime = $startdatehour
        TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
    }
    End = @{
        DateTime = $enddatehora
        TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
    }
    Location = @{
        DisplayName = $location
        LocationType = "Default"
    }
    IsOnlineMeeting = $true
    OnlineMeetingProvider = "teamsForBusiness"
    Attendees = $attendees
}

# Create event
New-MgUserEvent -UserId "a@a.net" -BodyParameter $params´´´
```

Comment: Please, show the C# code that you wrote to execute the PowerShell Script file.

Comment: To be honest, I would not recommend invoking a PowerShell script directly from your page. There might be some group policies on servers that will prevent you to do so. What if you use directly the MS Graph's endpoint to create an event for a user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http via a REST query?

Comment: I agree, but as I was having some problems with user validation and I had to solve the problem quickly, it seemed to me to be the best immediate solution... Now, I see that it is not.
Is there any documentation in C# that allows me to validate the user who will schedule the event?

Comment: Forgot to say... Everything is done on behalf of another user (the admin user...)

Comment: The MS Graph has a few endpoints if you want to work with users. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0. With the right permissions, your admin user will be able to get info about any user and the latter's calendars, contacts, groups, etc.